# Keyword arguments in torch.nn.Sequential (pytroch)

Tags: pytorch

a question regarding keywords in torch.nn.Sequential, it is possible in some way to forward keywords to specific models in a sequence?

```
    model = torch.nn.Sequential(model_0, MaxPoolingChannel(1))
    res = model(input_ids_2, keyword_test=mask)
```

here, keyword_test should be forwarded only to the first model.

Thank a lot and best regards!

my duplicate from - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/keyword-arguments-in-torch-nn-sequential/53282

Answer (score 2):

No; you cannot. This is only possible if all models passed to the [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Sequential) expects the argument you are trying to pass in their [`forward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.forward) method (at least at the time of writing this).

Two workarounds could be (I'm not aware of the whole case, but anticipated from the question):

- If your value is static, why not initializing your first model with that value, and access it during computation with `self.keyword_test`.
- In case the value is dynamic, you could have it as an inherent property in the input; hence, you can access it, also, during computation with `input_ids_2.keyword_test`